# grails override redirect controller method

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to override the default controller redirect method and cannot seem to get the following bit of code to work.

I have created a plugin and I'm trying to use the "doWithDynamicMethods" to replace the redirect.

```
def doWithDynamicMethods = {ctx ->
   application.controllerClasses.each() { controllerClass ->
      replaceRedirectMethod(controllerClass)
   }
}

void replaceRedirectMethod(controllerClass) {
   def oldRedirect = controllerClass.metaClass.pickMethod("redirect", [Map] as Class[])
   controllerClass.metaClass.redirect = { Map args, Map params ->
      // never seems to get here    
   }
}
```

Do I have the signature wrong or am I missing something? The reason I'm doing this is I'd like to change the uri of the redirect if a certain condition is met but with logging/print statements I see that it is going in the "replaceRedirectMethod" upon application startup/compile but it doesn't go in there when doing a redirect via the controller once the app is started.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the signature is wrong - redirect takes a single `Map` parameter (see the declaration in `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.ControllersGrailsPlugin.registerControllerMethods()`)

So it should be

```
controllerClass.metaClass.redirect = { Map args ->
   // pre-redirect logic
   oldRedirect.invoke delegate, args
   // post-redirect logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if you want the `redirect` method override to be reapplied after modifying the source code of a controller, you need to do the following:

```
def watchedResources = [
  "file:./grails-app/controllers/**/*Controller.groovy"]

def onChange = { event ->
  if(!(event.source instanceof Class)) return

  if(application.isArtefactOfType(ControllerArtefactHandler.TYPE, event.source))
  {
    replaceRedirectMethod(application.getArtefact(ControllerArtefactHandler.TYPE,
                                                  event.source.name))
  }
}
```