# Override Grails redirect method

Tags: grails

I'm carrying the locale of my Grails application in the URL, such as

http://myapp.com/LANG/controller/action/id.

Therefore, I adjusted the URLMappings.groovy with the language attribute. Since I would like to save work and don't apply the lang parameter at every link, I have overridden the g:link taglib with the language from params.lang. This works pretty good.

When I do a redirect from a controller, such as

```
redirect(action: "logout")
```

I'd like to append the params.lang automatically instead of writing every time

```
redirect(action: "logout", params: [lang: params.lang])
```

I found the thread [grails override redirect controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316727/grails-override-redirect-controller-method), but I'm unsure how to proceed. Where does this code take part?

How can I override the redirect() method and add the params.lang-attribute?

Please advice, thank you very much.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.3.6

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Depending on your answer, a better idea might be to not monkey with the param and instead get the information you need from the locale resolver bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in your application would be to use a bit of meta programming and the `BootStrap.groovy` for your Grails application. The following is just a simple example of what that might look like:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def ctx = servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
        def app = ctx.getBean("grailsApplication")
        app.controllerClasses.each() { controllerClass ->
            def oldRedirect = controllerClass.metaClass.pickMethod("redirect", [Map] as Class[])
            controllerClass.metaClass.redirect = { Map args ->
               // new pre-redirect logic
               if (!args['params']) args['params'] = [:] // just in case redirect was called without any parameters
               args['params']['whatever'] = 'something' // add something into the parameters map

               oldRedirect.invoke delegate, args
               // new post-redirect logic
            }
        }

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

The above example just wraps the implementation for `redirect` on all controllers within your Grails application and injects a new parameter called `whatever` with the value of `something`.

The above was tested (quickly) using Grails 2.4.2.

Comment: There are things about this approach that could be simplified.  One is you could skip the first couple of lines by just auto wiring the `grailsApplication` bean into the `BootStrap` instance.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Absolutely, this wasn't intended to be production ready code, but rather an example of what is possible. I thought perhaps being a bit more verbose would demonstrate that it's possible to access more than just an inejected bean.