# How to override redirect of grails 3 controller

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.3

I want to override(extend) the redirect method of a grails 3 controller.

In grails 2 this was done by overriding the method via metaClass. See [Override Grails redirect method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479666/override-grails-redirect-method/36500163#36500163)

Since grails 3 this is not working anymore.

What I want to achieve: I want to manipulate the argument map that is passed to the redirect method of every controller I implemented (filtered by package name)

Or to be more specific: I want to add/change the mapping param based on some small logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to override(extend) the redirect method of a grails 3
>   controller.

You can simply override the method as per usual language rules...

```
class DemoController {

    // ...

    void redirect(Map m) {
        // do whatever you like here...
    }
}
```

If you want to invoke the original `redirect` method you can do that too but you will need to explicitly implement the `Controller` trait...

```
import grails.artefact.Controller

class DemoController implements Controller {

    void redirect(Map m) {
        // do whatever you like here before
        // invoking the original redirect...

        // invoke the original redirect...
        Controller.super.redirect m
    }
}
```

Comment: The original question includes "a grails 3 controller" which implies you only want to do this in 1 controller.  The approach I would use in that case is described above.  If you wanted to apply this same method to numerous controllers, you have a number of other options, some of which also involve traits.

Comment: Thanks For the answer Jeff. Sorry for not describing that more in detail. Your second solution goes more in the direction I imagined. I still need the normal behavior of the redirect - I just want to extend it. I want to override the redirect for every of my controller classes with the same functionality. In order to follow the DRY principle, I would create an abstract class that implements the Controller trait and let every of my controllers inherit that?

Comment: "In order to follow the DRY principle, I would create an abstract class that implements the Controller trait and let every of my controllers inherit that?" - That could work but I think putting that logic in a trait instead of an abstract class is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try AST transformation with Type Annotation and `GroovyASTTransformation`. For example: take a look at - `groovy.transform.Sortable` annotation which injects `compareTo` method using `org.codehaus.groovy.transform.SortableASTTransformation`