# Access controller request params in BootStrap.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to grails and I am trying to override the redirect method in groovy controller. I refereed this [Override Grails redirect method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479666/override-grails-redirect-method/36500163#36500163). But I do not understand how do I access and pass the http request params to the redirect override in BootStrap.groovy.

```
redirect(action: "logout", params: [lang: params.lang])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement a wrapper via metaClass on a controller (just like mentioned in your linked question), you can simply access the "active" controller object via "delegate" in  your implementation closure:

```
def ctx = servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
def app = ctx.getBean("grailsApplication")
app.controllerClasses.each() { controllerClass ->
    def oldRedirect = controllerClass.metaClass.pickMethod("redirect", [Map] as Class[])
    controllerClass.metaClass.redirect = { Map args ->
        // delegate is the instance of <controllerClass> where "redirect" just gets executed.
        // the current http request can be accessed via a getter on controller classes
        println delegate.getRequest()
        oldRedirect.invoke delegate, args
    }
}
```

alternatively, you could use the RequestContextHolder to obtain the current requestAttributes and extract the request from there (see org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.CommonWebApi.java in Grails 2 or grails.web.api.ServletAttributes.groovy in Grails 3)